# How to display a screen and await for return data from within the widget tree

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to navigate the user to a screen to perform a local_auth (biometrics) before showing the home page etc... I've wrapped the call of the navigator within a FutureBuilder however, I'm receiving an error

> Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null

```
Future<bool> localAuthentication() async {
    var result =  await Navigator.push<bool>(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LocalAuthenticationScreen()));

        if(result is bool)
        {
          return result;
        }else{
          return false;
        }
  }
```

Within my widget tree I'm returning the following from within a blocBuilder

```
return FutureBuilder(
                      future: localAuthentication(),
                      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> authenticated) {
                            
                        if (authenticated.data) {
                          return BlocBuilder<UserBloc, UserState>(
                              builder: (context, state) {
                            //Take them to the home screen
                            if (state is UserLoaded) {
                              return MessageHandler(child: HomeScreen());
                            } else if (state is NoUserAvailable) {
                              //Take them to create a user profile
                              return CreateUserScreen();
                            } else if (state is UserLoadedNoDefaults) {
                              //Take them to create account and plan
                              return MessageHandler(
                                  child: CreateOrJoinScreen());
                            }
                          });
                        }else{
                          return UnAuthenticatedScreen();
                        }
                      });
```

I'm not sure whether this is the right approach, however I've used the futurebuilder to attempt to Future Bool value that I'm expecting to receive from LocalAuthenticationScreen.

***Update:*** I've also tried WidgetBinding to display the screen - this works however, since the logic on FutureBuilder (authenticated.hasdata) has already been evaluted I'm displayed with a UnAuthenticatedScreen.

```
Future<bool> localAuthentication(BuildContext _context) async {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      return Navigator.push<bool>(
              _context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (_context) => LocalAuthenticationScreen()))
          .then((result) {
        if (result is bool) {
          return result;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });

      return false;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the .then to resolve to get the fine result.

```
Future<bool> localAuthentication() async {
   return await Navigator.push<bool>(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LocalAuthenticationScreen())).then((result){
        if(result is bool)
        {
          return result;
        }else{
          return false;
        }
     });

   return false;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, however, the change using .then to resolve the result is still resulting in an error : Failed Assertion: boolean expression must not be null

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get this to work, so instead i reverted to using a bloc to manage the state. Not sure if this is best way, but it works.

```
return BlocBuilder<LocalauthBloc, LocalauthState>(
                          builder: (context, localauthState) {
                            if (localauthState is LocalauthInitial || localauthState is ReValidateUser) {
                              return LocalAuthenticationScreen();
                            } else if (localauthState is AuthenticatedUser) {
                              return BlocBuilder<UserBloc, UserState>(
                                  builder: (context, state) {
                                //Take them to the home screen
                                if (state is UserLoaded) {
                                  return MessageHandler(child: HomeScreen());
                                } else if (state is NoUserAvailable) {
                                  //Take them to create a user profile
                                  return CreateUserScreen();
                                } else if (state is UserLoadedNoDefaults) {
                                  //Take them to create account and plan
                                  return MessageHandler(
                                      child: CreateOrJoinScreen());
                                }
                              });
                            } else if (localauthState is UnAuthenticatedUser) {
                              return UnAuthenticatedScreen();
                            }
                          },
                        );
```